# Facebook login button onlogin="function" gives ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

By this far I've managed to implement a facebook login button on my page. 
The login works well, but I'd like to call a function in my login.js code when the login has succeeded.

Im using the onlogin from [This link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) that will trigger my userLogin() function.

My problem is that when I'm logging in to the application I get this ReferenceError:

[ReferenceError: userLogin is not defined --- sdk.js:1:1]

I have no clue why I got this error.

All of my javascript code is placed in a .js file and included at the top of .

Relevant code:

userLogin() which is placed in $(document).ready(function() {...});

```
// This function is called when someone finishes with the Login Button.
function userLogin () {
    console.log("it worked");
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);

    });

}
```

HTML-code, button that will trigger the function:

```
<body>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div class="loginButton">
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="userLogin();">
</fb:login-button>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is defined within the scope of `$(document).ready()`, and not outside.

To make it available globally, you can do this in your `login.js`:

```
var userLogin;

$(document).ready(function(){
    userLogin = function(){ /* ... */ };
});
```

> **Note:** `userLogin` is a name that *could* interfere with another library that might use the same name if it is defined globally. To avoid that kind of problems, I'd advise you to give it a more "custom" name, like `myUserLogin`.

Comment: +1 You saved my day, thank you, the call back function was not triggering and this what solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The function has to be defined on the window. The solution is:

```
// somewhere before the button is rendered
window.loginCallback = res => {
    // handle response logic
}

    <div
      className="fb-login-button"
      data-max-rows="1"
      data-size="large"
      data-button-type="continue_with"
      data-onlogin="loginCallback();"
    ></div>
```